# AngularJS-Array to cookiestore

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, cookiestore

having trouble storing arrays in cookiestore. 
trying to add the array into the cookiestore so  that it could be accessed later.
JS

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);
function CartForm($scope, $cookieStore) {
$scope.invoice.items = $cookieStore.get('items');
$scope.addItem = function() {
$scope.invoice.items.push({
    qty: 1,
    description: '',
    cost: 0
 });
$scope.invoice.items = $cookieStore.put('items');
},

 $scope.removeItem = function(index) {
 $scope.invoice.items.splice(index, 1);
 $scope.invoice.items = $cookieStore.put('items');
},

$scope.total = function() {
 var total = 0;
 angular.forEach($scope.invoice.items, function(item) {
     total += item.qty * item.cost;
 })

 return total;
 }
   }
```

Comment: have you solved this @user3428728 problem

Answer (score 0):

Store data in cookie: put(key, value);

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);

function CartForm($scope, $cookieStore) {

$scope.invoice.items = $cookieStore.get('items') || [];

$scope.addItem = function() {
    $scope.invoice.items.push({
        qty: 1,
        description: '',
        cost: 0
    });
    $cookieStore.put('items', $scope.invoice.items);
};

$scope.removeItem = function(index) {
    $scope.invoice.items.splice(index, 1);
    $cookieStore.put('items', $scope.invoice.items);
};

$scope.total = function() {
    var total = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.invoice.items, function(item) {
        total += item.qty * item.cost;
    });
    return total;
};
}
```